# UIViewController is not deallocated after dismiss

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a MainViewController and presenting another view controller VC1. From VC1 I'm presenting another view controller VC2. I'm passing date from VC2->VC1->MainViewController using closures.

VC2->VC1 value passed and VC2 dismissed
VC1->MainViewController value passed and VC1 dismissed

Once MainViewController receives the data from VC2 it pushes another view controller VC3.

UIViewController VC2 is not deinitialized after dismissing. I receive socket data in VC2 even after it is dismissed and values passed repeatedly to MainViewController. And MainViewController pushes VC3 multiple times.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @objc func goToVC1() {
        let vc1 = VC1()
        vc1.callBack = { [weak self] result in
            let vc3 = VC3()
            vc3.result = result
            self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc3, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
class VC1: UIViewController {

    var callBack: ((String)->Void)?

    @objc func goToVC2() {
        let vc2 = VC2()
        vc2.callBack = { [weak self] result in
            self?.callBack?(result)
            self?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    @objc func gotDataHere(_ string: String) {
        self.callBack?(string)
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
class VC2: UIViewController {

    var callBack: ((String)->Void)?

    @objc func methodCalledRepeatedly(_ string: String) {
        self.callBack?(string)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
class VC3: UIViewController {
    var result: String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(result)//Printed repeatedly
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the closure code

Comment: The view controller references in the closure are most likely not being deallocated - have a look at `weak` and `unowned` in the [Swift Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID52).

Comment: @George_E I'm using weak. Let me update the code

Comment: @AamirR Updated my question with code

Comment: this isn't the complete code I guess, I think there is a timer that calls methodCalledRepeatedly, it could be the problem

Comment: @iDevid I dont have any timer

Comment: how do you call methodCalledRepeatedly?

Comment: As I've mentioned in my question I receive response from socket

Comment: @George_E I've added my code